# Velocity.js clearing default values after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I have elements on a page that I want to animate in to view, but after they've animated in, I want to defer further animation on them to CSS (by changing classes)... I am finding that Velocity leaves all my animated properties in the `style=` tag and makes CSS transitions impossible.

I have ***a*** solution below, but resetting the CSS on complete seems *iffy*, I was wondering if there's a better way to do it?

```
// first use CSS to hide the element and squish it
$el.css({ 
    width: 0, 
    left: "-10px", 
    opacity: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    transition: "none"
})

// now animate the width and margin (do this first
// so there's a little gap between existing elements
// before we fade in new element.
.velocity({ 
    width: width,
    marginRight: margin
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 230
})

// then fade and move in the new element,
// but this is the iffy bit when it completes
// I have to unset all the styles I've animated?
.velocity({ 
    left: 0, 
    opacity: 1 
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 100,
    delay: 130,
    complete: function(els) {

        $(els).css({
            width: "",
            left: "",
            opacity: "",
            marginRight: "",
            transition: ""
         });             
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, you *want* animation engines to leave styles inline; otherwise final values will pop as they get overwritten by stylesheets upon removal.

You can also do `$(els).attr("style", "");` to just clear all styles.

Comment: Thanks, @execution, that clears it up! :) - I think i'll re-factor it based on your answer :)

Comment: Perhaps, a cleaner approach would use $(els).removeAttr("style").  The aspect to consider is sometimes you are animated CSS elements that JQuery's .css() method can't reach. Then, see Velocity's 'hook' method.